# How to add new and multiple rows to a dataframe using apply (based on a user-defined function)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

for my use case the original frame looks like -

| index | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | zeroth eg | reject |
| 1 | 1 | first eg | accept |
| 2 | 2 | second eg | accept |
| 3 | 3 | third eg | reject |

I have a function defined as -

```
def foo(row):
  if row['col1']==0:
    answers = ['zero']
  elif row['col1']==1:
    answers = ['one', 'i']
  elif row['col1']==2:
    answers = ['two', 'ii']
  else:
    answers = ['three', 'iii']
```

Based on this function I want to add a new column called col4 to my dataframe. Essentially, as many new rows need to be added as there are values in the `answers` list where col4's value in each row should be the subsequent values of the list (while values for all other columns remain same)

So I want the resulting frame to be like -

| index | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | zeroth eg | reject | zero |
| 1 | 1 | first eg | accept | one |
| 2 | 1 | first eg | accept | i |
| 3 | 2 | second eg | accept | two |
| 4 | 2 | second eg | accept | ii |
| 5 | 3 | third eg | reject | three |
| 6 | 3 | third eg | reject | iii |

I cannot understand how can we use apply to return rows and that too, multiple rows. Below code will just add a new column col4 to my original frame containing lists (if I return answers in `foo`)

`input_df['col4'] = input_df.apply(foo, axis=1)`

How can I modify `foo` to return multiple rows?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try return list then `explode`

```py
def foo(row):
  if row['col1']==0:
    answers = ['zero']
  elif row['col1']==1:
    answers = ['one', 'i']
  elif row['col1']==2:
    answers = ['two', 'ii']
  else:
    answers = ['three', 'iii']

  return answers

input_df['col4'] = input_df.apply(foo, axis=1)
input_df = input_df.explode('col4', ignore_index=True)
```

```
print(input_df)

   index  col1       col2    col3   col4
0      0     0  zeroth eg  reject   zero
1      1     1   first eg  accept    one
2      1     1   first eg  accept      i
3      2     2  second eg  accept    two
4      2     2  second eg  accept     ii
5      3     3   third eg  reject  three
6      3     3   third eg  reject    iii
```